# Executing multiple update statements in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have three update statements to be executed in PHP, i am getting the values of all these as return parameters. How to execute each statement independely and finally show the end user the result that it has been successfully updated.

```
<?php 

        public function name($parameter1,$parameter2.... $parametern) {


        }

 ?>
```

Then how finally we can get the result in my row object.

Comment: Not clear what you are asking - where is the select statement to return data? Are you expecting an update statement to return the rows it updated? Are you calling a PL/SQL routine? Your code fetches the result of a null query then you ask "how we can get the result in my rows object" - surely just assign it to a member variable. Your post is too confusing.

Comment: show your 3 update statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah i think i see, well looks to me from your update statements that you want to update 3 different tables which all depend on 'tycodashboard'.

In that case i advise you use transactions to retain a bit of data integrity, otherwise say if one fails? you'll have lost some data. As a general rule, if you need to do more than 1 update simultaneously use transactions.

Heres a great article on the subject: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html

Its quite easy to do, just make you sure your tables are using the INNODB, then all you have to do is append START TRANSACTION to the top of your sql script and then COMMIT at the end.

You might be trying to combine too much into a single function, whenever i'm updating multiple tables, it's easier to just handle each one in turn, rather than trying to stuff them all into one return. So try making a function that saves it, returning success or failure, then call it from your main function for each one of your sql scripts passing in the values.

```
//This is the function that gets called from your page.
public function my_called_function() {

    //your sql script (using "" means you can put variables in without having to remove the quotes)
    $sql = "UPDATE....SET 'col' = $_POST['myvalue']";

    //Run your script and get result
    $result = $this->save_my_stuff($sql);

    //if not null means success!
    if($result) {
        echo 'success!'; // your success message
    }
    else {
        echo 'something bad happened'; //your failure message
    }
}

//this is the function that does the saving!
private function save_my_stuff($sql_script) {

    //Make connection
    $conn = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
    //Check connection
    if(!$conn) {
        //connection failed
        die('Could not connect: '.mysql_error());
    }

    //Select your database using your connection object
    mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $conn);

    //try and save
    try {
        //run the query
        $result = mysql_query($sql_script, $conn);

        //return the result
        return mysql_result($result);
    }
    catch (Exception $e) {
        //deal with exception
        return null;
    }

    //close connection
    mysql_close();
}
```